# Runtime Class creation in actionscript-why and for what purpose?

Tags: actionscript-3, class, runtime

Hi
Recently in actionscript it has been made possible to create Classes at runtime. Thi seems quite cool, but I am perplexed thinking of a situation in which this might be useful. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a reference or sample code?  What exactly are you talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the uses for this in ActionScript is limited.  So start of understanding what it actually is, and how other languages use it.

See Self-modifying code on wiki:
http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-modifying_code

Also see Reflection:
http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_science)

As an example of how it might be useful, I'm currently working with genetic algorithms to modify code at runtime.  This way I can test every permutation (varying initial values and methods) without having to create classes for them, with the added bonus of exporting a .swf only containing the winning permutation.